# Requirejs callback undefined on code splitting

Tags: reactjs, requirejs, code-splitting

I'm a newbie to [RequireJS](https://requirejs.org/) I have a ReactJS app with `index.jsx` as an entry point

```
// index.jsx

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


export function callBackForRequirejs() {
    return "testing";
}
```

When I load my build via RequireJS I get these callbacks

```
require(["/path/to/bundle"], function(callback) {
    console.log(callback) // I get "callBackForRequirejs"
}, function(err){
    console.log(err)
});
```

But when I do code splitting I'm getting undefined in the callback, for code splitting I'm using these configs

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            commons: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: "vendor",
                    chunks: "initial",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Actually, my react app is a plugin for some external app, the external app loads my plugin via RequireJS. The code inside an external app is something like this

case 1:

```
require(['/pathof/my/react/plugin/bundle.js'],
    function(callbackwhenpluginloads){
        callbackwhenpluginloads()
    })
```

Since the size of my bundle.js is very large so I decided to split it into two parts one which comes from `node_modules` and one from `my code`

Now the external plugin loads my react plugin something like this

case 2:

```
require(['/pathof/my/react/plugin/bundle.js', 
'/pathof/my/react/plugin/vendor.js' ], function(callbackwhenpluginloads){
    callbackwhenpluginloads()  // callbackwhenpluginloads is undefined 
})
```

I'm getting `undefined` callback when the external app loads my plugin in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, based on RequireJS [docs](https://requirejs.org/docs/start.html) for starting you did the following way and it works well:

```
require(['/path/to/bundle.js'], function(callback) {
  console.log(callback) // you get callbackForRequireJS
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error)
});
```

And now you did a code-splitting on your project, so you should consider this the `vendor.js` is like a dependency to split `bundle.js` file. so you should follow [this example](https://github.com/volojs/create-template/blob/master/www/app.js) to load the dependencies at the first and then run the other split code. so your code is something like below:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    reactApp: 'path/to/bundle.js'
  },
  deps: ['path/to/vendor.js'],
});


require(['reactApp'], function(callback) {
  console.log(callback) // it should works now
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error)
});
```

Or there is another way that I don't recommend it:

```
require(['path/to/vendor.js'], function() {
  require(['path/to/bundle.js'], function(callback) {
    console.log(callback) // it should works now
  }, function(bundleError) {
    console.log('bundleError', bundleError)
  });
}, function(vendorError) {
  console.log('vendorError', vendorError)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, for code splitting you are using the webpack. webpack and require js don't really get along.

you should try vanilla JS instead.

```
<script onload="handleOnLoad()" />
```

Or go for a npm package.
[react-load-script - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-load-script)